# Loss and accuracy remains unchanged

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I was making a classifier with 8 classes. This is my model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(16, 3, padding="same", activation="relu", input_shape=(100,100,1)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D())
model.add(Conv2D(32, 3, padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D())
model.add(Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D())
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(len(classes)))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(
    x_train, y_train,
    validation_data = (x_test, y_test),
    epochs = 20,
    batch_size= 64
)
```

The loss and accuracy of this model remains constant.
I don't know why. Can anyone tell what to do?

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of conditions that your accuracy and loss stay the same. It really depends on your data, your data size, your parameter settings, or even your random weights for keras model. But sometimes, it's just because your model it's not suitable for solving your issue, and you can build a better one. If you think the above are not the case you involved, could you please provide more details about your code or data information?

Comment: I have less training images about 1000. What should i do in such case?

Comment: I have 8 classes

Comment: If you don't mind, may I see your training outputs? I mean the training accuracy and loss for each epoch